# Which should I choose?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, gerunds

> The package can be torn......by pulling on the red tab located at the top left corner of the box.

A.open

B.opening

C.to open

D.opened

and please explain your option.

Answer (score 3):

> The package can be torn **open**...

*Open* is an adjective complement to the verb *tear*: it designates the state which the action of the verb effects in the package. Tearing the package causes it to be open.

In the 'canonical' active form of this sentence *the package* would be the object, so *open* is often called an 'object complement' or 'object-oriented complement':

> He tore [<sub>obj</sub>the package] [<sub>comp</sub>**open**].

But your example is cast in the passive voice, and the canonical-form 'object' is cast as subject, so the term 'object complement' is misleading. Let's call it a 'Patient complement' instead, with 'Patient' designating the object which is acted upon.

With many verbs a Patient complement is obligatory—causative *make*, for instance, or verbs of caused motion. Depending on the verb the complement may be an adjective phrase, a preposition phrase, or a noun phrase:

> He makes [<sub>obj</sub>Janet] [<sub>comp</sub>**happy**].
>   She put [<sub>obj</sub>the teacup] [<sub>comp</sub>**on the shelf**].
>   The company named [<sub>obj</sub>Henderson] [<sub>comp</sub>**CEO**].

Many other verbs do not require a Patient complement but do take one freely—*tear* in your example, for instance. Such optional complements are often called 'secondary complements' (but the scope of that term varies with different authorities).

Patient complements are of course only possible with transitive verbs—verbs which take a Patient as an object in canonical-form sentences. Intransitive verbs often take Agent complements, complements which designate a state present or effected in the subject Agent:

> He has risen [<sub>comp</sub>**very high**].
>   John flew [<sub>comp</sub>**to New York**] last night.
>   Ancient Greek athletes competed [<sub>comp</sub>**naked**].

Comment: Isn't it a [phrasal verb](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tear-something-open)?

Comment: @user178049 That depends on what you mean by that term, which has at least three distinct and incompatible meanings. In my grammatical sect, no, it's not.

Comment: I think a adverb modifies a verb. **Open** is a adjective . Why can it modify the verb **tear**.

Comment: @PhamVanDuc It does not modify the verb *tear*: it is a predicative *complement* of *tear* which describes *the package*, just as it is a predicative complement of *be* which describes *the package* in "The package is open".

Comment: But I usually see the following of a verb is a adverb, not a adjective
Can you explain this problem,please?

Comment: @PhamVanDuc Suppose you say "I am confused"--do you think *confused* is an adverb, because it follows the verb? Of course not: it's an adjective describing you. *Tear open* works the same way: *open* isn't an adverb modifying *tear* but an adjective describing the subject *the package*.

Answer (score 0):

*Torn open* is correct. The reason that A is the correct form is that *open* functions as an adverb modifying *tear* in this case rather than a verb, so forms of the verb do not apply.

Combinations such as this are called *phrasal verbs*. Phrasal verbs combine a verb with an adverb or preposition (sometimes more than one e.g. *add up to*) to form an idiomatic meaning.

Other phrasal verbs using *tear* are *tear up*, *tear down*, *tear apart*, *tear off* and *tear out*, among others. For a list of phrasal verbs and their meanings, see [this](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/phrasal-verbs-list.htm).

Comment: I searched the [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open) ..
**Open** isn't a adverb, it is adjective.

Comment: @PhamVanDuc In this context, 'open' is an adverbial particle in the phrasal verb "tear open".